# dojo widget; Object [object Object] has no method 'transitionTo'?

Tags: dojo, transition

i create a div "divNodes0" with dojo.create and want to do a transition like this:

```
var actualNodeListItem = dijit.registry.byId("divNodes0");
alert(actualNodeListItem);
alert(dijit.registry.byId("divAlarms"));
actualNodeListItem.transitionTo("divAlarms");
```

the first alert says "[Widget dojox.mobile.ScrollableView,divNodes0]" and the second the same for divAlarms so both widgets are created and the transition should work but i get the following error:
Object [object Object] has no method 'transitionTo'

why has my widget no method transitionTo, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the alert widget name, I assume you're working with the widget class `dojox/mobile/ScrollableView`.  According to the [API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView), `ScrollableView`, much like the error says has no `transitionTo` method.  It does have something that sounds similar:

`performTransition(moveTo, transitionDir, transition, context, method)`